# When the destroy() has been declared?

Tags: java

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
            InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Creating Process");

        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("notepad.exe");

        System.out.println("Waiting for 3 Sec");

        Thread.sleep(3000);

        process.destroy();

        System.out.println("process Destroyed");
    }
}
```

As far as I know `Process` Class is an abstract class and it has this method for `destroy()`
`abstract void destroy();`

But as you can see when I invoke the `destroy` method for the `process` Object it knows exactly what to do!

When this method has been declared ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [java.lang.Process](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html):

"The `ProcessBuilder.start()` and `Runtime.exec` methods create a native process and return an **instance of a subclass of Process** that can be used to control the process and obtain information about it."

It is the job of the subclass to define `destroy()`.

And from `ProcessImpl.java` we have:

```
/* This class is for the exclusive use of ProcessBuilder.start() to
 * create new processes.

...

public void destroy() { terminateProcess(handle); }
```

Answer (score 2):

Process is an abstract class, but what you get from `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("notepad.exe")` is an instance of a concrete subclass of Process. In this concrete subclass, there is an implementation for the abstract `destroy()` method.

You don't need to know which concrete subclass is returned. What matters is that it's a Process. Chances are that the concrete subclass used on Windows is different than the one used on MacOS or Linux. But they all are subclasses of Process. That's what polymorphism is.

Comment: You are too quick for me :/

Comment: Thanks sir .. I almost got what you are telling me .. Any way .. can we put our hand on the implementation for the destroy() method itself?  the one that running for windows .. ?

Comment: @WaseemSwaileh: why do you want that?